# Send POST request in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape a website in which I need to send a POST request to a form to query data. Here is the code I'm using.

```
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36"}

with requests.Session() as s:
    
    r = s.get('https://data.rabbu.com', headers=headers)
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    hidden = soup.find_all("input", {'type':'hidden'})
    payload = {x["name"]: x["value"] for x in hidden}
    payload['search'] = '16101 Tampa Street, Brooksville FL 34604'
    payload['bedrooms'] = '2'
    
    r = s.post('https://data.rabbu.com/e', headers=headers, data=payload)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    print(soup.text)
```

But I'm unable to send properly the POST request because I'm getting the following error message:

```
"The change you wanted was rejected (422)"
```

I tried to use the "json" argument instead of "data" - to no avail.

Do you have any idea how I can bypass this issue? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I did not get into your question deeply, but probably the problem is that you send request without Cookie in headers

Comment: How can I send cookies in headers? Where can I get that from in this particular website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parameters need to be changed. Try the following:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36"}

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get('https://data.rabbu.com', headers=headers)
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    hidden = soup.find_all("input", {'type':'hidden'})
    
    payload = {x["name"]: x["value"] for x in hidden}
    payload['estimate[address]'] = '16101 Tampa Street, Brooksville FL 34604'
    payload['estimate[bedrooms]'] = '2'
    r = s.post('https://data.rabbu.com/e', headers=headers, params=payload)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    
    print(soup.title.text)
```

Giving you:

```
16101 Tampa St, Brooksville, FL 34604, USA | Revenue Projection: $1,639/mo | 2 to 2bds | 13 comps | Rabbu
```